# Agrarian skies - world seed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-feed-the-beast

After reading [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172680/no-land-to-start-on-agrarian-skies) I understand agrarian skies modpack generates the world with nothing in it.

I recently found a world seed with multiple small biomes very close to each other, an ideal world for me.

I want to re-use this world, but start again on agrarian skies (nothing in the world, HQM totally reset, thaumcraft reset, etc.).

I have tried:

- Generating a new world and traveling to the exact co-ordinates of my old world. This seems to have different biomes (due to it being a new seed).
- Copying my old world and attempting to remove all player added blocks manually. (this is far too time consuming, not an ideal solution, though possible if nothing else exists).
- Copying the world and removing the region directory. (this seems to generate a new seed, rather than use the old seed and generate a new world).

Is it possible to generate a new agrarian skies world from my seed so that I have a blank world with all these small biomes?

If not, is it possible to take the old agrarian skies world directory and convert it into a blank one?

Or, is there a command to remove all player added blocks?

---

#### Extra info

This is on Agrarian skies multiplayer using agrarian skies v3.1.2 (I think).

I generate the world via the server startup.

Apologies for multiple questions, but I think they all relate to the same problem.

The world seed is 3922357017991451086, if it makes any difference.

Comment: The question space isn't meant to be used to comment on answers.  You can comment on the answers themselves, but don't use the question space for that purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used Agrarian Skies, I assume you can't just enter a world seed into the normal seed box when creating a new world?

If not, you're left with one of two options:

1. If you already have a world with the correct seed, then use [a utility like MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/) to bulk clear out all blocks.
2. If you have a world that you want to use, but it *doesn't* have the right seed, you can use [a utility like NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac) to view and edit the save file, and change the world seed.

Comment: This world is generated via a server for multiplayer if that makes any difference. I should have mentioned that, sorry. Thanks for the answer, I had forgotten about MCEdit. I will give it a try when I get a chance.

Comment: @MattLishman The only difference between a single-player and a multi-player world is that the dimensions are in separate folders (its own separate "world" in technical terms)

Comment: This works and allowed me to further edit the world as I saw fit. Thanks. However, for anyone looking to simply generate a new world from a world seed, use Commandhat's answer. That is the simplest.

Answer (score 3):

When you're starting a Minecraft multiplayer server, you can add a setting to your server.properties file called `level-seed: <data>` to force a predetermined seed to be used regardless of world settings.

*Watch out, though!*

- If you remove the `level-seed` tag, then the server may forget which seed is being used and retrieve a new one.
- If you don't use a file editor that understands Unix newlines, your server.properties file might end up very screwy looking.

More info on server.properties: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This worked. However, I chose Brad's answer because it fit my specific requirements more. Anyone looking to just use the world seed should use this answer though, it's the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just fly up in creative mode to the skyblock and do `/jspawn set`. See as [No land to start on Agrarian Skies?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172680/no-land-to-start-on-agrarian-skies)